# Check which ASP.NET was clicked

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following div (normally hidden)

```
<div id="confirmDialog" class="window" style="background-color:#f2f4f7; border:1px solid #d9a0e2; text-align:center; height:100px; position:fixed;  padding:10px;  top:50%  " runat="server" visible="false">
<br /> You already have a leave request on the chosen date. Are you sure you want to submit this request?<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="BtnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Yes"  Width="60px" />&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="BtnNo" runat="server" Text="Cancel" onclick="BtnNo_Click" />
</div>
```

When a user clicks submit, code starts to execute and if the below function is true I would like to show a confirmation dialog before continuing to execute code:

```
protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some validations
    if (new LeaveLogic().GetEmployeeLeaveRequestByDate(username, Convert.ToDateTime(TxtBoxDate.Text)) > 0)
    {
           confirmDialog.Visible = true;
           /if BtnConfirm is click continue to execute code 
           //else stop
```

How can I do this via asp.net/jQuery?

Comment: Check the `sender` object, it will return control info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must split the code in 2 different parts: one that executes and after is done pops up a confirmation dialog, and a second part where you submit the form to execute the remaining piece. You can't do this in one shot because you can't have server-side code execute, pop up a confirm dialog on the client side and then continue on the server side.

What you have to do is (in pseudo code)

```
button1_Click()
{
  Execute_logic;
  use scriptmanager to trigger a JavaScript function that displays the confirmation dialog;
}
```

The JavaScript function should:

```
function askConfirm()
{

  if(confirm('want to continue?'))
     submit_the_form to execute second part of the process();
  else 
     return false;
}
```

Server-side code again:

```
//This is the method that should execute after the JavaScript function submits the form
Handler_ForSecondPartOfTheRequest()
{
  execute second part of the logic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in couple of ways.

1. By intercepting the click event by Jquery
2. Other adding script in your code.

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScriptManager CSM = Page.ClientScript;
        if (!ReturnValue())
        {
            string strconfirm = "<script>if(!window.confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location.href='Default.aspx'}</script>";
            CSM.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Confirm", strconfirm, false);
        }
    }
    bool ReturnValue()
    {
        return false;
    }
```